# app crashes while rotating the device in either direction of iPAD

Tags: ios, ios5

let me brief my app , i have root view Tab Bar controller (5 tabs), 1st view is a navigation controller; its an iPad App. NOW  i have a table view on which i am making header via CODE .

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
 { 
    _headerScenarioIDLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
   //and many more declarations here

}
```

and rotating the view accordingly from

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(fromInterfaceOrientation))
    {// for portrait.
     _headerScenarioIDLabel.frame        = CGRectMake(-30, 2, 125, 20);
    }
   else
   { // for LandScape
          _headerScenarioIDLabel.frame        = CGRectMake(-26, 2, 125, 20);
    }
}
```

Now the issue is this code is working Perfectly when i launch the application & rotate it but  when i enter into the Navigation and return back from navigation then the app crashes on further rotation .

THREAD 1 EXE BAD ACCESS, 0x1bd109b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi

can any one suggest where i am wrong for this weird crash.. ???

Comment: Did you check if the `BAD ACCESS` is due to `_headerScenarioIDLabel`? Try commenting out the code related to `_headerScenarioIDLabel` and see if it still crashes.

Comment: yup on commenting the code it works fine ..

Comment: Then it seems that `_headerScenarioIDLabel` has been `autoreleased` and you are trying to access the old address location. You should ensure that you retrieve the current value of `_headerScenarioIDLabel` again before performing any more operations on it for autorotate.

Comment: yup autorelease is the root cause of crash. but dude i am not much familiar with coding can you kindly brief me how to do this .. Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: That's difficult to do without looking at your entire code. You will have to debug this on your own and try to ensure that either `_headerScenarioIDLabel` is _not_ released OR it holds the correct address of the label. At the same time you should take care of memory leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you code with the static analyzer for leaks. Also the first thing I see is that you're initializing the ivar `_headerScenarioIDLabel` with an autoreleased object - you need to fix this as the ivar should hold a strong pointer to the header view. Also keep in mind that the method `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` could be called more than once, that's why you need to release this ivar before setting it again. The simple solution to all those problems is to use **properties**... and **always** use properties, especially when using manual memory management.

Comment: well dude after removing the autorelease it works without crash :). , i have used properties also .Now as you said tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method can be called more than once then how to use this ??  AND on Removing autorelease the app has locked to the launching orientation (on rotating the header label dosent change). I am not much familiar with coding so kindly give some more details.